# Is there a way to see which Beans were registered through component scanning?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to determine which beans are picked up by the Spring Boot component scanning mechanism vs which are picked up by auto-configuration etc. Have not been able to find a way to do this, is this possible?

I'd like to know this because I'm going to use the `spring-context-indexer` to create a `META-INF/spring.components` file in my application JAR. However, I pull in other libraries/jars and am wondering if this will break my app if those JARs provide beans that rely on component scanning to be registered.

Comment: Why don't you just get the beans' classes and filter out the ones that aren't in your scanned packages?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a nicer way to do this, but you could get some of that information through `AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext::getBeanDefinition` (you can autowire the context).

```
// Bean from autoconfiguration
// Can check the factory bean name and see that it has 
// the "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure" package
// to determine that it's probably from autoconfiguration
BeanDefinition autoConfigDef = context.getBeanDefinition("dispatcherServletRegistration");
autoConfigDef.getFactoryBeanName(); // org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletRegistrationConfiguration
autoConfigDef.getFactoryMethodName(); // dispatcherServletRegistration

// Bean from my configuration @Bean + @Configuration
// If it has a factory bean name and it doesn't have the 
// Spring autoconfiguration package, it's probably from one of our
// own configurations
BeanDefinition myConfigDef = context.getBeanDefinition("myConverter");
myConfigDef.getFactoryBeanName(); // me.demo.MyConfiguration
myConfigDef.getFactoryBeanMethod(); // myConverter

// Bean annotated with @Component and discovered via component scan
// Doesn't have a configuration associated with it, so it was probably
// detected via the @Component annotation
BeanDefinition componentDef = context.getBeanDefinition("myController");
componentDef.getFactoryBeanName(); // null
componentDef.getFactoryBeanMethod(); // null
```

If others know cleaner methods, I would also love to know how.